# Working with axis XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my XML:

```
<NTC_SECTION_LIGHTLISPRODUCT>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST>
        <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
            <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
                <REGION>17-Mar Tirreno - Italia (Sardegna)</REGION>
                <VICINITY>PORTO TORRES</VICINITY>
            </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
            <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
                <REGION>12-Mediterraneo Occidentale - Italia (Sardegna)</REGION>
                <VICINITY>PORTO MADDALENA</VICINITY>
            </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
            <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
                <REGION>17-Mar Tirreno - Italia (Sardegna)</REGION>
                <VICINITY>PORTO DI SIRACUSA</VICINITY> 
            </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST>
</NTC_SECTION_LIGHTLISPRODUCT>
```

This data of region e vicinity and ather data are put into a table(without specific order).

Thi is my XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:for-each select="NTC_SECTION_LIGHTLISPRODUCT">
    <xsl:for-each select="SECTION_CONTENT_LIST">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM">
                    <xsl:for-each select="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT/REGION">
                    ....
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT/VICINITY">
                    ....
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This XSLt in output create a UNIQUE TABLE with the value of Region and Vicinity.

**My request:**
**I would create a new table (separated by BR/) every time change value of REGION -substring-after(REGION, '-')- in order to have:**

|-------------------------------|
|PORTO TORRES
|-------------------------------|
|PORTO DI SIRACUSA
|-------------------------------|


|-------------------------------|
|PORTO MADDALENA
|-------------------------------|

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Since you're using XSLT 1.0, try searching on "muenchian grouping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read up on [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

In your case, it looks like you are grouping `NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT` by `REGION` (or perhaps the substring-after '-' as you briefly mention)

```
 <xsl:key name="region" match="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT" use="substring-after(REGION, '-')" />
```

Then, you would start off by getting each `NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT` for the first occurrence of each possible `REGION` (i.e The distinct regions)

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('region', substring-after(REGION, '-'))[1])]">
```

Then, you can get the items in this 'group' (the items with the same region), by simply using the key:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="key('region', substring-after(REGION, '-'))" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="region" match="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT" use="substring-after(REGION, '-')" />

    <xsl:template match="NTC_SECTION_LIGHTLISPRODUCT">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('region', substring-after(REGION, '-'))[1])]">
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(REGION, '-')" /></h1>
            <table>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('region', substring-after(REGION, '-'))" />
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="VICINITY" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the following:

```
<h1>Mar Tirreno - Italia (Sardegna)</h1>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>PORTO TORRES</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>PORTO DI SIRACUSA</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<h1>Mediterraneo Occidentale - Italia (Sardegna)</h1>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>PORTO MADDALENA</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```